# Git post-receive hooks

Tags: git, hook, git-post-receive

I have two different servers. One is for **repository** and another one for **web application**.
I'm trying to setup **post-receive hook.** When I push code into repository server then I want project codes to be in application server.

**Server**

```
$ mkdir /home/yo/repo.git
$ cd /home/yo/repo.git
$ git init --bare
$ cd /hooks
$ touch post-receive.sh
$ chmod +x post-receive.sh
```

**post-receive.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
git --work-tree=appuser@appserver:/var/www/multiverse --git-dir=/home/yo/repo.git checkout -f
done
```

**Local**

```
$ cd /home/Sites/multiverse
$ git init
$ git remote add origin repouser@reposerver:/home/yo/repot.git
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "initial commit"
$ git push origin master
```

**How can I achieve this using post-receive?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `post-receive` script must be installed inside the `hooks` directory of the bare git (`/home/yo/repo.git/hooks`) and must be named `post-receive` without any extension.